# How can I collect all the objects with the same or extended classes in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm developing a WordPress plugin where I want to connect different apps. I created a class 'App' and I'm extending the 'App' class with different classes.

Now I would like to collect all the objects of those instances so I can list them out.

Anyone who can help me out? If interested I'm even willing to pay a good developer who can teach me this for future development. Looking forward to your replies.

This is my current code:

```
class App {

    public function __construct( $id, $name, $label, $description, $subscription_id ) {
        $this->id              = $id;
        $this->name            = $name;
        $this->label           = $label;
        $this->description     = $description;
        $this->subscription_id = $subscription_id;
    }
}
class App_Vimeo extends App {

    public function __construct( $id, $name, $label, $description, $subscription_id ) {
        $this->id              = $id;
        $this->name            = $name;
        $this->label           = $label;
        $this->description     = $description;
        $this->subscription_id = $subscription_id;
    }
}

class App_Facebook extends App {

    public function __construct( $id, $name, $label, $description, $subscription_id ) {
        $this->id              = $id;
        $this->name            = $name;
        $this->label           = $label;
        $this->description     = $description;
        $this->subscription_id = $subscription_id;
    }
}

class Get_Apps {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->get_apps();
    }

    public static function get_apps() {
        $apps   = array();
        $apps[] = new App_Vimeo( 1, 'vimeo', 'Vimeo', 'Vimeo app description', 1 );
        $apps[] = new App_Facebook( 1, 'facebook', 'Facebook', 'Facebook app description', 1 );
        return $apps;
    }
}

$apps = Get_Apps::get_apps();
var_dump( $apps );
`
```

Comment: Read [ask] first.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for reaching out. What did I do wrong so I can learn about it?

Comment: Anyone who can help me out on dynamically gathering objects of classes?

Answer (score 0):

have a go with this:

```
$apps = Get_Apps::get_apps();
foreach($apps as $a) {
    echo get_class($a) . '<HR>';
}
```

The [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function returns the name of the class in which the parameter object identifies itself as.

Comment: Thanks. They thing I'm looking for is how I can collect the objects of each class I use throughout the code. So when I add a new object eg. $woocommerce = new App( 'Woocommerce' ) it should be added to some kind of array where I can call it directly. Now I added the objects of the class 'App' manually via get_apps() to get my listing working. Thanks for your reply.